# Xcode linking error in a program that works using Makefile

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, boost

I'm currently trying to fork the program [qme-ng](https://github.com/mp-bull/qme-ng). It seems that everything works if I use my Makefile. On the other hand if I want to use Xcode weird things happen.

Here is my Makefile:

```
CC=g++
CCFLAGS=-D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D__cplusplus -O3 -march=native
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib -lboost_program_options -lgmp -lgmpxx
SRCDIR=src
INC=-I./include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/boost/include

all: qme-ng
Exception.o: $(SRCDIR)/Exception.cpp
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< $(INC) -c
greenSizeHash.o: $(SRCDIR)/greenSizeHash.cpp
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< $(INC) -c
carquois.o: $(SRCDIR)/carquois.cpp Exception.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< $(INC) -c
iceQuiver.o: $(SRCDIR)/iceQuiver.cpp Exception.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< $(INC) -c
mutexplorator.o: $(SRCDIR)/mutexplorator.cpp quiver.o Exception.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< $(INC) -c
greenexplorator.o: $(SRCDIR)/greenexplorator.cpp greenSizeHash.o iceQuiver.o Exception.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< $(INC) -c
greenfinder.o: $(SRCDIR)/greenfinder.cpp iceQuiver.o Exception.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< $(INC) -c
mutexploratorSeq.o: $(SRCDIR)/mutexploratorSeq.cpp quiver.o Exception.o mutexplorator.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< $(INC) -c
rng.o: $(SRCDIR)/rng.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< $(INC) -c
naututil.o: $(SRCDIR)/naututil.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< $(INC) -c
nauty.o: $(SRCDIR)/nauty.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< $(INC) -c
nautil.o: $(SRCDIR)/nautil.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< $(INC) -c
nausparse.o : $(SRCDIR)/nausparse.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< $(INC) -c
naugraph.o : $(SRCDIR)/naugraph.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< $(INC) -c
nautinv.o : $(SRCDIR)/nautinv.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< $(INC) -c

qme-ng: qme-ng.cpp greenexplorator.o greenfinder.o mutexploratorSeq.o mutexplorator.o greenSizeHash.o iceQuiver.o quiver.o Exception.o nautil.o rng.o nauty.o naututil.o nausparse.o naugraph.o nautinv.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INC) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

clean:
    -rm -f *.o qme-ng *.cpp~ src/*.cpp~ include/*.hpp~ src/*.c~ include/*.h~
```

On Xcode my header search paths are `"$PROJECT_DIR"/include` `/usr/local/include` `/usr/local/boost/include`. My library search paths are `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/boost/lib`. `libboost_program_options.dylib`, `libgmp.dylib` and `libgmpxx.dylib` are in my "Link Binary With Libraries". I have also copied the three libraries to `$PROJECT_DIR` as some web page suggests.

Currently I have the Apple Mach-O Linker Error below:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "GreenFinder::find(unsigned long long)", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "GreenFinder::GreenFinder(IceQuiver, __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>, int, int)", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "GreenExplorator::greenExploration(IceQuiver)", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "GreenExplorator::GreenExplorator()", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "GreenExplorator::~GreenExplorator()", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "MutExploratorSeq::getNbNeighboursMax()", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "MutExploratorSeq::isAcyclic()", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "MutExploratorSeq::dumpFiles(char const*)", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "MutExploratorSeq::MutExploratorSeq()", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "MutExploratorSeq::~MutExploratorSeq()", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "IceQuiver::generateGreenVertices()", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "IceQuiver::print()", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "IceQuiver::IceQuiver(Quiver)", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "IceQuiver::IceQuiver(char const*)", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "IceQuiver::IceQuiver(IceQuiver const&)", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "IceQuiver::~IceQuiver()", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "Quiver::Quiver(char const*)", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "Quiver::Quiver(Quiver const&)", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "Quiver::Quiver(int, int, int)", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "Quiver::~Quiver()", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
  "Exception::Exception(char const*)", referenced from:
  _main in qme-ng.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

EDITED: I have refactored the program to translate most French words into English. Hence the words have been changed.

Comment: You should provide a screenshot of your project navigator, based on the error it looks like you haven't included the source files. Are you sure they are being compiled and linked in?

Comment: Sure! I think the source files have been included. When I deliberately add some nonsense to a source file I do receive errors.

Comment: Are greenfinder.cpp etc in your project ? Do they show up under Build Phases/Compile Sources ? Also, did you inadvertently add some .o files to your project (e.g. qmg-ng.o) ?

Comment: @MobileBen I think your diagnosis of the problem is correct. I'm new to Xcode. It seems that I can't even use Xcode to get a small test project linked. The symptoms are the same. I can easily compile after changing the Header Search Path. However linking does not work.

Comment: You should clarify how you are "adding files" to the project. In either case, some screenies below should hopefully help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Project Navigator. You should see files in a few places as to if it is being compiled and linked.

[image]

The image above shows you the Project Navigator. The Build Phases will show you if the files are being compiled.

The next thing you need to check would be looking at the File Inspector. It shows you which targets the files belong to.

[image]

Comment: Xcode, provided you have this setup, should be able to link the compiled objects.